# Is there a way to add multiple values with same ID in two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and mySQL, I need to add multiple values in 2 mysql tables : the first table would have the more important informations and the second one would have the less important informations about each items.

To be more clear, ONE element would have his informations split in two tables.

(I need this for some reasons but two of them are : having the first table the less weight possible, and the second table would store datas that will be erase after a short time (meanwhile the first table keeps all the datas it stored).)

In the best scenario, I'd like to add a row in each table about one item/element with the same id in each table. Something like this :

> Table 1 id|data_1_a|data_1_b|...

> Table 2 id|data_2_a|data_2_b|...

So if I add an element which get the ID "12345" in the table 1, it adds the datas in the table 2 with the same ID "12345".

To achieve this, I think of two solutions :

1. Create the ID myself for each element (instead of having an auto_increment on table 1). The con is that it would probably be better to check if the ID doesn't already exist in the tables everytime I generate an ID...
2. Add the element on table 1, get its ID with $db->lastInsertId(); and use it to add the element's datas on table 2. The con is that I have to add one element by one element to get all the IDs, while most of the time I want to add a lot of elements (like one, two or three hundreds !) at once

Maybe there's a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: A better way would be to store it all in one table. You're making an arbitrary and unnecessary distinction between the different fields, which sound like they all belong to one entity and should be in one table. The reasons you've given for separating it don't make much sense and wouldn't cause any real problem even with one table

Comment: I understand your point of view @ADyson , but isn't it more optimize to not store some useless datas for nothing in a big table ? The datas in the second table are usefull for a while and then can be deleted after a few weeks, i'm not sure it would be usefull to keep them...

Comment: No it's not particularly more optimised. If anything, less so because you keep needing to join the tables for queries, and you need double the number of inserts and updates to add or change it. You can easily make those columns null after a few weeks if you don't need the data. But keeping it isn't a problem either - if you don't want to see those fields then don't select them. And unless you have vast amounts of data (millions and millions of rows) then I doubt storage space is really a big issue.

Comment: Humm... I get your point @ADyson and I'll think about that, thank you for your interest and your point of view !

Answer (score 2):

`lastInsertId()` reports the first value generated by the last `INSERT` statement executed. It's reliable to assume that when you insert many rows, they are given consecutive id values following that first value. For example, the MySQL JDBC driver relies on this assumption, so it can report the set of id values generated.

This assumption breaks only if you deliberately set `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2` (interleaved). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html for details about that.

But if it were my task, I would still choose to use a single table. When you find you don't need some of the columns anymore, use `UPDATE` to set them to NULL. This will eliminate the problems you're facing with assuring the same id is used across two tables.

Comment: Writing the post, I was thinking about something like that haha, thank you for the information :) . And I take your point of view in consideration, I'll think about the best way to do all that. Thanks !